# Supplement and letters

Tags: publications, journals

What does it mean for journal to be "letters journal" and "supplement journal"? For example, Nuovo Cimento (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuovo_Cimento) journal has this distinction.

Is "letter" a synonymum for "note"?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between letter, communication and journal paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58190/what-is-the-difference-between-letter-communication-and-journal-paper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letters are supposed to be short articles with innovative content, easy to communicate for the general scientific community.

From the Physical Review Letters website:

> It publishes short, high quality reports of significant and notable
>   results in the full arc of fundamental and interdisciplinary physics
>   research.

I've never heard about that another definition, seems like it is specific from the Nuovo Cimento journal. I would think that it publishes long articles with exhaustive detailed technical/theoretical reports.